# Pin Like Tool for compile time injection of instrumentation code

Tags: c++, c, llvm, intel-pin

As you might know, [PIN](http://www.pintool.org/) is a dynamic binary instrumentation tool. By using Pin for example, I can instrument every load and store in my application. I was wondering If there is a similar tool which injects code at compile time (Using a higher level of information, not requiring us to write the LLVM pass), rather than at runtime like Pin. I am especially interested for such kind of tool for LLVM.

Answer (score 1):

You could write [LLVM passes](http://llvm.org/docs/WritingAnLLVMPass.html) of your own and apply them on your code to "instrument" it during compile time. These work on LLVM IR and produce LLVM IR, so for some tasks this will be a very natural thing to do and for other tasks it might be cumbersome or difficult (because of the differences between LLVM and IR and the source language). It depends.

Comment: As If I didn't already know that, genius :)! I was talking about a tool that can do it for you at somewhat a higher level, for example I tell the tool to do so and so at each load and so and so at each store. Ofcourse I can write my own pass, but that was not my question.

Comment: So why not take that approach? What do you have in mind that would better suit your needs?

Comment: Because its more difficult to do it myself, than let a tool write a pass for me. I just need to say it to do so and so for some event, just like in case of Pin. So basically I want a tool that can create a pass for us.

Comment: Based on my experience with LLVM passes and my more limited experience with the Pin APIs, they're quite similar, I don't think there's such a big difference. One nice trick is to use llc -march=c++ to produce LLVM C++ API code that constructs the IR for the C/C++ code you feed it (does that make sense?), if like most mortals you find it easier to code what you want to do in C/C++ than to call the C++ API to produce the IR for it, that can come in very handy.